# Help with Cohomologies and Homologies

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

My algebraic skills are very weak, so in answering please assume I know close to nothing about algebra, geometry, forms, or the like.

I am trying to compute homologies and cohomologies. For examples, stuff like
$$H^2(S^2;Z_2)$$
$$H^2(P^2,Z_2)$$
$$H^2(K^2,Z_p)$$
$$H_2(S^2;z_2)$$
$$H_1(K^2)$$
$$H_2(K^2)$$
$$H^2(K^2,Z)$$
where we have the sphere, projective plane, and Klein bottle, but I am sure we could imagine more.

Let's try, apparently (just me guessing), 
$$H^2(S^2;Z_2)=H^2(\Delta^*(S^2;Z_2))=\frac{Ker\left(\delta:Hom(\Delta_2(S^2);Z_2)\to Hom(\Delta_3(S^2);Z_2)\right)}{Im\left(\delta:Hom(\Delta_1(S^2);Z_2)\to Hom(\Delta_2(S^2);Z_2)\right)}$$

where $\delta$ is the "natural map" defined on the "chain" of homomorphic groups from the simplecies, $\Delta_n(S^2)$, to $Z_2$.

In general, given a nice family (we need an extra property like "split") of exact sequences (like simplexes on a Manifold), $$0\to A_n\to B_n\to C_n\to 0$$ then we can take an arbitrary group, $G$ (if we take $G=\mathbb{R}$ then we have dual spaces), and form a new family of induced exact sequences, $$0\to Hom(C_n,G)\to Hom(B_n,G) \to Hom(A_n,G)\to 0,$$ we then can induce an infinite long sequence by cohomologying the above sequence, $$0\to H^0(C_0;G)\to H^0(B_0;G)\to H^0(A_0;G)\to H^1(C_1;G)\to\cdots$$ likewise we can instead of using "Hom" (and split exact sequences) we can use the "tensor product" (and some other property on the exact sequences) and arrive at another family of exact sequences (like the p-forms on a manifold) and induce another infinite long sequence by homologying, $$\cdots\to H_1(C_1;G)\to H_0(A_0;G)\to H_0(B_0;G)\to H_0(C_0;G)\to 0.$$

I really have no idea what I am saying. I have only a vague notion of why some of this might be true. Overall, I (kind of) understand that we are working through the derivatives and integrals of a manifold which is abstractly related to "Hom"ing and "Tensor"ing (these are related to notions of projective and injective).

But after all the symbols and theorems are read (online or in books), I ask myself simple questions like,

What the (insert language) is $Hom(\mathbb{R},Z_2)$? or for that matter $Hom(\Delta_2(S^2),Z_2)$? It seems that these calculations are needed in order to calculate the homologies and cohomologies above. But I really have no idea. What are the tricks of the trade? One last thing, does everything stated above even make sense? or is what was stated above pure fiction?

Any help would be welcomed, although I would prefer not to be pointed to an abstract book to read (already read a lot of them and I am still confused).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the right thing to do is to understand this in the context of de Rham cohomology, where the cohomology groups actually have a tangible meaning.  In fact, I think that may be where cohomology was invented, and things like simplicial cohomology were invented later by analogy which might explain why they don't seem particularly well-motivated.

In any case, this is treated in a pretty readable manner in "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology" by Bott and Tu.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this book. However I should point out that the de Rham cohomology collapses all the notions above into simple wedge products, dual spaces, and impeded simplexes by setting $G=\mathbb{R}$, in which case, calculations are easier naturally, since we can think of actual differentiation and integration. It is the abstract, arbitrary $G$ that I am having trouble with, where notions of dual space, wedge product, and the like are no longer tangible. Calculations now need to be performed with exact sequences, something that is eluding me.

Comment: I don't think that an arbitrary cohomology group actually means anything that a human can understand.  The ideas are motivated by the case of things like de Rham or Dolbeault cohomology, or by simplicial homology.  It turns out that they can be boiled down to a small number of axioms, and consequently generalize immensely, but I don't think there's much intuitive meaning to, say, a simplicial cohomology group *per se*.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. I am solely interested in how to calculate these homologies and cohomologies, what are the tricks? For example (apparently), $$H_2(K^2)\approx Z\oplus Z_2.$$ Another example (apparently), $$H^2(S^2;Z_2)\approx H^2(P^2;Z_2).$$ How were these calculations done? Are they trivial? How do people find these calculations? I don't understand.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of different questions here.  Perhaps you should break them up into individual questions, e.g. "How can I calculate the homology of the Klein bottle?"